# Found long, needs Boolean (Inserting into SQLite [Android])

Tags: java, android, sqlite

For some reason, my return statement returns a long as opposed to a boolean, can't progress to test anything unless this is resolved. I have no idea why it is even doing this. Tried everything within the scope of my knowledge, hence why I am here.

Looked at some other people's examples before I posted and they seemed to use the same return statement as I have, with no issue.

```
public boolean updateDatabase(String Name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(COL_1, Name);
    return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, args);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: This code would not run anyway because `db.close` is after a return statement.

Answer (score 1):

The insert API returns the ID of the row inserted, or -1 on error. And your return is before the db.close() statement, that won't compile.

See here:  [insert](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

Comment: I see, why does it matter if the close() is after the return statement. Surely I would want to return the row ID and then release the reference to the database object ?

Plus, as I have no rows in my database, shouldn't it just return 1 in which case this is the first row? I have defined that the ID is an auto-incrementing field in my "CREATE_QUERY".

Comment: With all due respect, if you have to ask why the return needs to be at the end of the function, you need to brush up on basics. Your code doesn't even compile as is.

Comment: Every time I post on this forum, somebody has to be a massively pretentious arsehole. I genuinely want to ask why ? Your first comment was fine ! It really helped me understand more about the problem. I was just following up on a question that your response had generated.

I know what a return statement does. What i'm asking is, if you deference the object that is storing the database before you get a return value, then how can you expect to get a return value? Look at all the other examples of this problem.. they show the 'SQLiteDatabase.close()' method .. AFTER the return statement.

Comment: @TomDunwoody Please show a link to such an example.

Comment: I thought I had a text example but I noticed he had the close after the insert statement. I'm pretty sure it was a YouTube video, some Indian guy call PAREESH explaining how to insert data into an SQLite database.

Either way, such a response (2nd) from Francesc was completely unneeded and not a good display of constructive criticism.

Comment: @Tom Durwoody Did you miss the "with all due respect" part? What part is unneeded? I'm not the one name calling after all.